# Use env context within uses defined jobs

Tags: github, github-actions

With a `job` defined by `uses` keyword.
Is it possible to use workflow defined `env` context ?

If not, is there anyway to define variables in one place or pass context to share workflow env context without having to repeat variables `jobs`?

Sample:

```yaml
name: Build and Publish Helm charts
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"
env:
  FOO: BAR
jobs:
  test:
    uses: '.github/workflows/test.yaml'
    with:
      FOO: ${{ env.FOO }}
```

While I would expect `test.yaml` to take `BAR` in the `FOO` input,
testing above scripts throws an `Unrecognized named-value: 'env'` error.

Basically, I want to define variables that are valid for all jobs of a workflow but not in other workflows.

Answer (score 2):

As you're using reusable workflows, according to its [Limitations](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#limitations) the env vars are not propagated:

> - Any environment variables set in an `env` context defined at the workflow level in the caller workflow are not propagated to the called workflow. ...

Alternatively:

> - To reuse variables in multiple workflows, set them at the organization, repository, or environment levels and reference them using the `vars` context. ...